# Nested structs using gorm model

Tags: go, go-gorm

I have struct called User:

```
type User struct {
    Email string
    Name string
}
```

and struct called UserDALModel:

```
type UserDALModel struct {
    gorm.Model
    models.User
}
```

gorm Model looks like this:

```
type Model struct {
    ID        uint `gorm:"primary_key"`
    CreatedAt time.Time
    UpdatedAt time.Time
    DeletedAt *time.Time `sql:"index"`
}
```

this is possible to make UserDALModel nested with gorm model and user model so the output will be:

```
{
    ID
    CreatedAt
    UpdatedAt
    DeletedAt
    Email 
    Name
}
```

now the output is:

```
{
    Model: {
        ID
        CreatedAt
        UpdatedAt
        DeletedAt
    }
    User: {
        Name
        Email
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer:

```
type UserModel struct {
    Email string
    Name string
}

type UserDALModel struct {
    gorm.Model
    *UserModal
}

------------------------------

user := UserModel{"name", "email@email.com"}
userDALModel := UserDALModel{}
userDal.UserModal = &user
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this test](https://github.com/jinzhu/gorm/blob/master/embedded_struct_test.go) in gorm, I think you need to add an `embedded` tag to the struct.

```
type UserDALModel struct {
    gorm.Model `gorm:"embedded"`
    models.User `gorm:"embedded"`
}
```

You can also specify a prefix if you want with `embedded_prefix`.

Answer (score 0):

be careful embedding two structs with the same column:

```
package tests

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/jinzhu/gorm"
    _ "github.com/jinzhu/gorm/dialects/mysql"
    "testing"
)

type A struct {
    X string
    Y string
}

type B struct {
    X string
    Y string
}

type AB struct {
    B B `gorm:"embedded"` // Embedded struct B before struct A
    A A `gorm:"embedded"`
}

var DB *gorm.DB

func connectDB() error {
    var err error
    spec := "slumberuser:password@tcp(localhost:3306)/slumber"
    DB, err = gorm.Open("mysql", spec+"?parseTime=true&loc=UTC&charset=utf8")
    DB.LogMode(true) // Print SQL statements
    //defer DB.Close()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}

// cd tests
// go test -run TestGormEmbed
func TestGormEmbed(t *testing.T) {
    if err := connectDB(); err != nil {
        t.Errorf("error connecting to db %v", err)
    }
    values := []interface{}{&A{}, &B{}}
    for _, value := range values {
        DB.DropTable(value)
    }
    if err := DB.AutoMigrate(values...).Error; err != nil {
        panic(fmt.Sprintf("No error should happen when create table, but got %+v", err))
    }
    DB.Save(&A{X: "AX1", Y: "AY1"})
    DB.Save(&A{X: "AX2", Y: "AY2"})
    DB.Save(&B{X: "BX1", Y: "BY1"})
    DB.Save(&B{X: "BX2", Y: "BY2"})

    //select * from `as` join `bs`;
    //  # x,y,x,y
    //  # AX1,AY1,BX1,BY1
    //  # AX2,AY2,BX1,BY1
    //  # AX1,AY1,BX2,BY2
    //  # AX2,AY2,BX2,BY2

    var abs []AB
    DB.Select("*").
    Table("as").
    Joins("join bs").
        Find(&abs)
    for _, ab := range abs {
        fmt.Println(ab.A, ab.B)
    }
    // if it worked it should print

    //{AX1 AY1} {BX1 BY1}
    //{AX2 AY2} {BX1 BY1}
    //{AX1 AY1} {BX2 BY2}
    //{AX2 AY2} {BX2 BY2}

    // but actually prints
    //{BX1 BY1} {AX1 AY1}
    //{BX1 BY1} {AX2 AY2}
    //{BX2 BY2} {AX1 AY1}
    //{BX2 BY2} {AX2 AY2}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In GORM 2.0 you have to use tag `embeddedPrefix` instead of `embedded_prefix`.

Also you can use the `embedded` tag not only for embedded structures, but also for nested structures. In that case you give a name to the substruct and you can use multiple nested structs of the same type.

```
type contact struct {
    Text string `json:"label"`
    Link string `json:"value"`
}

type SupportContacts struct {
    Phone contact `json:"phone" gorm:"embedded;embeddedPrefix:phone_"`
    Email contact `json:"email" gorm:"embedded;embeddedPrefix:email_"`
}
```